# Ratio of 2 Sums of products of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial, gamma-function

I want to prove that for $k \ even, 0 \leq k<n, n\in \mathbb{N}$:

$-\frac{1}{(2n-3-k)(k+2)}\sum \limits_{i=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^{i} 2^{i} (2n-2-i)!}{(n-1-i)!i!(k-i)!}=\sum \limits_{i=0}^{k+2} \frac{(-1)^{i} 2^{i} (2n-2-i)!}{(n-1-i)!i!(k+2-i)!}$ (1).

I tried similar things like induction over $k$ or saying sth useful about $\frac{(-1)^{i} 2^{i} (2n-2-i)!}{(n-1-i)!i!(k-i)!}$.

When I compute $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^{i} 2^{i} (2n-2-i)!}{(n-1-i)!i!(k-i)!}$ in Maple, I get
$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^{i} 2^{i} (2n-2-i)!}{(n-1-i)!i!(k-i)!}=\frac{- \pi (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}k+n}2^{2n}}{4 \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}k-n+\frac{3}{2})\Gamma(k+1) \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}k)}$ (2).

With (2) it is not too complicated to prove (1).

Are there any ideas how to tackle (1) or (2)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{#c00000}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{i\ =\ 0}^{k}{\pars{-1}^{i}2^{i}\pars{2n - 2 - i}!\over
\pars{n - 1 - i}!\, i!\, \pars{k - i}!}}
={\pars{n - 1}! \over k!}
\color{#c00000}{\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{k}{2n - 2 - j \choose n - 1 - j}
{k \choose j}\pars{-2}^{j}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{k}{2n - 2 - j \choose n - 1 - j}{k \choose j}\pars{-2}^{j}}
> =\sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{k}{k \choose j}\pars{-2}^{j}\ \overbrace{%
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2 - j} \over z^{n - j}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{{2n - 2 - j \choose n - 1 - j}}}}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2} \over z^{n}}
> \sum_{j\ =\ 0}^{k}{k \choose j}\pars{-\,{2z \over 1 + z}}^{j}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2} \over z^{n}}
> \bracks{1 + \pars{-\,{2z \over 1 + z}}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2 - k}\pars{1 - z}^{k} \over z^{n}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\,\lim_{z\ \to\ 0}
> \partiald[n - 1]{\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2 - k}\pars{1 - z}^{k}}}{z}
> \end{align}

Then,
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{i\ =\ 0}^{k}{\pars{-1}^{i}2^{i}\pars{2n - 2 - i}!\over
\pars{n - 1 - i}!\, i!\, \pars{k - i}!}
={1 \over k!}\,\lim_{z\ \to\ 0}
\partiald[n - 1]{\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2 - k}\pars{1 - z}^{k}}}{z}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

To tackle $(2)$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^i 2^i (2n-2-i)!}{(n-1-i)!i!(k-i)!}&=&\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\frac{(-1)^i 2^i(2n-2-i)!}{(n-1-i)!}\\&=&\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}(-1)^i 2^i B(2n-2-i,n-1)\\&=&\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}(-2)^i \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n x^{2n-1-i}\,dx\\&=&\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n x^{2n-1}\left(\frac{x-2}{x}\right)^k\,dx.\end{eqnarray*}$$